# How to update a field with random numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, random

I have to update all the rows of the **TaxId** column in my table with random numbers.

```
UPDATE myTable
SET TaxID = abs(checksum(NewId()) % 10000)
```

I tried the above code on one record, and it updated the TaxId with a random number of ONLY 4 digits. How do I get it to update with 9 random digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase zeros in mod as below

```
UPDATE myTable
 SET TaxID = abs(checksum(NewId()) % 1000000000)
```